# Plotting multiple plots using ggplot and facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, facet-wrap

Sample data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(c(1:3), each = 4*10), 
                        year = rep(rep(c(1980:1983), each = 10), times = 3),
                        day = rep(1:10, times = 3*4),
                        x = sample(123:200, 4*3*10, replace = T),
                        start = 123,
                        end = 200)
```

I want to save the plot of each `loc.id` for all years in a single page using `facet_wrap` and each `loc.id` in separate pages as a pdf. Following
loop does this:

```
loc.vec <- 1:3

pdf("my.pdf")

for(l in  seq_along(loc.vec)){

  loc.id <- loc.vec[l]
  df.sub <- df[df$loc.id == loc.id,]

  pp <- ggplot(df.sub,aes(x = day, y = x)) + geom_line() +
          facet_wrap(~year) + 
          geom_vline(aes(xintercept = df.sub$start)) + 
          geom_vline(aes(xintercept = df.sub$end))
  print(pp)
}
dev.off()
```

Can I achieve without the loop?

Thanks

Comment: whats the problem with using a loop?

Comment: The no. of `loc.id` I have is way too many. So was wondering if there is any quicker solution to this. Don't mind using a loop

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but I can hazard a guess why.  Your question includes code that works fine.  There's no way around needing some kind of loop here, and your original choice of `for` is as good as any from a functional viewpoint.  You may get a range of answers suggesting to use `map` or `apply` or `by` or any of the many other ways of looping in R. But none of them changes the underying fact that you need to repeat an operation several times iterating over loc.id. In other words you need a loop and you already have one that works just fine.

Comment: Fair point. I guess I was more talking about from a speed perspective i.e. if I had 1 million `loc.id`, would this loop will still be faster compared to the solution below.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would want a million page pdf. In any case the time to generate each plot far exceeds any overhead from a loop, so you won't get any speedup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `purrr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

f_plot <- function(id) {
  df %>%
    filter(loc.id == id) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x = day, y = x)) + 
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~year) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = start)) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = end))
}

pdf("my2.pdf")
map(loc.vec, f_plot)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider `by` (being the object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) to slice dataframe by the *loc.vec* factor and run subsets through plot:

```
process_plots <- function(df.sub) {    
  ggplot(df.sub, aes(x = day, y = x)) + 
    geom_line() + facet_wrap(~year) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = df.sub$start)) + 
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = df.sub$end))      
}

pdf("my.pdf")    
by(df, df$loc.vec, process_plots)
dev.off()
```